# Proper representation for manipulation of 0 and 1 sequences in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, binary

This is probably a very basic question but I would appreciate some input. I am working on a Python script for cryptography and I need to be manipulating various sizes of 0 and 1 sequences representing data and key.

At the moment, I am using either strings of 0/1 or integer numpy arrays to represent the sequences. However I feel that this is not the proper way to work and even though it is currently working it might lead to unexpected issues down the road. I believe one possible explanation would be that I haven't fully understood why the binary data type is in fact in hex.

Anyway, I would appreciate any help on that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

A `'0110'` `str`, or a `np.array`, could be a
perfectly fine way to represent key material,
cleartext, or ciphertext.

You might prefer `bytes`, as perhaps the most
natural representation. It is 1:1 with numpy's
`uint8` array representation.

See e.g. this HMAC: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation ,
or the [blake2b signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.blake2b).

In the end it may come down to whichever
representation is most convenient for the
code that is calling you.